# CMD FTP Issues Works on Server 2012, Not on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, ftp

I have the below command script running as a scheduled task on my Win 2012 Server without any issues.  I want to replicate this on a clients Win 7 x64 computer.

```
echo user [username]>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo [my password]>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo bin>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo mkdir web2>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo cd web2>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo mkdir clientpc_%date:~-2,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo cd clientpc_%date:~-2,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo ascii>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo quote pasv>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo mput c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\backup_temp\*.*>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo quit>> c:\ftp1.dat
echo bye>> c:\ftp1.dat
ftp -n -s:c:\ftp1.dat -i ftp.livedrive.com
del c:\ftp1.dat
```

However, when I get to mput, the command prompt informs me

1. 200 PORT COMMAND SUCCESSFUL
2. 150 Accepting Data Connection

At which point the process just hangs.  No error, no timeout, nothing.  I mean nothing for 5-10 minutes.

The setup is running Norton 360 which has the Firewall switched off.

I've also tried active mode.

Note that the earlier MKDIR commands work, so presumably there is no server contact issue.  I can't seem to find any help on the web.  Everyone with my issue seems to get a timeout issue, but thats not the case here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its a connection issue. FTP needs a control connections for basic commands like login and mkdir, and for the real data transfer it opens another TCP connection: in passive mode the server opens a listener on a random port and tells the client about its address and in active mode the client opens a listener on a random port and tells the server about it.

The control connection is working for your, but the data connection not. This means, that there is something restricting the connectivity, e.g. some kind of firewall either on your computer, the server computer or somewhere in between.

Comment: I wonder if its Norton.  I've had it before when its off, its not actually off.  I'll stop it from starting & see what I get...

Comment: Now getting Error opening local file ????..